# Make the Current Rails application on the server point to a previous release

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, capistrano

How do you change the current release of a Ruby on Rails application that was pushed up to an Ubuntu server with Capistrano to an earlier release?
[image]

These files are located in /var/www/application/current
I want to go back to the rails application dated Sep 30 and put it into var/www/application/current which is currently pointing to a release dated Oct 11

I am currently running Ubuntu 12.04, Rails 3.2.7 and Ruby 1.9.3

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the current is a link to the release folder so all you have to do is point it to a different release folder ie

```
ln -s 20120930184735 current
```

and restart the app
keep in mind if there were migration changes you might have to roll them back as well ...

Answer (score 0):

Capistrano has a build in task to do what you want:

```
cap deploy:rollback

# or:

cap deploy:rollback:code
```

Select the one which suites you more.

[Documentation](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/Capistrano-Tasks#deploy%3arollback)